# JS React не могу найти src файл, чтобы работать в редакторе кода

Tags: javascript, node.js, файлы, reactjs

Скачала node, редактор кода - Visual Studio Code, не могу найти никак, уже напрямую открыла папку node_moduls, но всё равно нет нужных файлов, index.js, CSS, HTML и т.д. Насколько знаю - находятся они в src, а где этот src? т_т

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Comment: Не можете найти src реакта или приложения написанного на реакте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы открыли коренную папку npm, судя по скриншоту, а не папку проекта на React.

Comment: А где можно найти папку этого проекта? Я где-то указала путь уже?

Comment: Вы же запустили откуда-то локальный сервер. В той же папке и должен лежать проект.